# How to use ionic in cordova with plain javascript?

Tags: cordova, ionic4

So i'm trying to use Ionic 4 on a plain javascript for my cordova project. What i did was installing ionic using npm.

Then i create a cordova project:

```
cordova create testion
```

Then add android platform

```
cordova platform add android
```

After that i go into the newly created cordova directory and run this:

```
npm install @ionic/core
```

then copied all the content of **node_modules/@ionic** to **www** and in my *index.html* i import the ionic like so:

```
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="core/dist/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="core/css/ionic.bundle.css">
</head>
```

Then i run it on my android:

```
cordova run android
```

What i got was a blank page with this error on the console:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. - core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js:1

The app works ok if i run it on browser by using:

```
cordova run browser
```

Am i doing anything wrong? please help. thank you

UPDATE: I tested this on my Galaxy J5 Pro running Android 7.0

Comment: put your script link in the body

Comment: @user9088454 tried it. but still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Running this command `npm run build --es5` should fix the error. If not please show the complete HTML code also.

And also I don't understand why you ran the code `npm install @ionic/core`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried it but not working. the reason im using `npm install @ionic/core` is to retrieve the ionic library so that my app could work offline. i follow the step from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425420/how-to-use-ionic-4-css-and-js-without-cdn-in-a-static-website#answer-54453154)